# Push content in container down on click, load content into space revealed Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a container full of content.  Im trying to click a button, and push all the content downward, say 700px.  Once the content is pushed down, a new page loads into the space that is now revealed because the content is pushed down.  Im going to also want to push that same button to play the animation in reverse, push the content up while unloading the newly loaded content.

How would i do this with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jquery Effects and Manipulation API

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

These steps should suffice

1. Insert an empty DIV over your current content DIV.
2. Using CSS either move the content DIV down (by adding a top margin) or add a bottom margin to your empty DIV
3. Populate your new DIV with content
4. If you want to reverse it, just remove the margin you added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="showHideTopContent">Show Hide Content</button>

<div id="container">
    <div id="topContent" style="display:none;">
        This is top content
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div id="topContent" style="display:none;">
        This is bottom content.
    </div>        
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#showHideTopContent").click(toggleTopContent);
    });

    function toggleTopContent() {
      var topContent = $("#topContent");
      var bottomContent = $("#bottomContent");

      if(!topContent.is(":hidden")) {
        topContent.hide();
        bottomContent.slideUp("slow");
      } else {
        // if you want the content to come from AJAX or so do it here
        //       ....
        //   If you do so, the topContent div should remain there, but empty.

        $("#topContent").slideDown("slow");
      }
    }
</script>
```