# Push content in container down on click, load content into space revealed Jquery - Part 2

Tags: jquery, css

Before I begin, please reference this link which is Part 1 of my issue:

[Push content in container down on click, load content into space revealed Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113569/push-content-in-container-down-on-click-load-content-into-space-revealed-jquery/5113681#5113681)

Now this is what it looks like after I've implemented the code from the prior example:

http://flexbeltsite.info/TestPages/SlideUpandDown.html

Its close, but not 100% what i want. When you click the button for the 2nd time, I want the animation to play exactly in reverse, at the same slow speed... bringing the container back to the top, and hiding the top content.  Currently, the code im using is making the entire page disappear totally when the button is pressed the second time.  I do not want that.

*-Bonus-*

I also would like to, if at all possible, lock the header to the bottom of the page at a min-height when the button is first pressed to slide down.  The header would only be able to come up only so high when the window is shrunk, but if the window is fully expanded, the header is locked to the bottom of the page.  In a nutshell, You basically will see the header become the footer when the button is first pressed.

Not only that, I want to remove the ability to scroll the page down so that you can see the slid down container contents.  There should be no scroll bars once the container drops after pressing the slide down button.

*-Final Bonus-*

I would like to externally load another page automatically into the topContent div once the container is slid down and the top content is fully revealed.

I hope I can get help on this. Itd also be great if the coders who provide answers have contact info avaliable in case I need to need to follow up on your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised your Jquery code for the first part of your question:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $("#MyProfile_Button").click(toggleTopContent);
    });

    function toggleTopContent() {
      var topContent = $("#topContent");
      var bottomContent = $("#Container");

      if(!topContent.is(":hidden")) {
        topContent.slideUp("slow");
      } else {
        // if you want the content to come from AJAX or so do it here
        //       ....
        //   If you do so, the topContent div should remain there, but empty.

        $("#topContent").slideDown("slow");
        //$("#Container").slideUp("slow");
      }
    }
</script>
```

See it action--you can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bTSr/

**Bonus Question 1**

Sounds like you need to set the height of the `#topContent` to document to the `$(window).height` - `$(#header).height`, which would push your header into the correct position.  This combined with an `overflow : hidden` on the `body` will disable your scroll bars.

I'll have a fiddle shortly.

**Edit:**

Here's a fiddle showing the above idea: http://jsfiddle.net/L9sSv/  -- I'm not manipulating your CSS or other code much, mainly just the Jquery. Hopefully this starts pointing you in the right direction.

For the second bonus question, you'd want to use Jquery's `.load()` after your `slidedown` (or potentially as a callback function,) which you can read about [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)--I'm sure you can get the rest! ;)

**Edit:**

Check out this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/wgYMQ/

Basically I took the `overflow : hidden` off the body tag stylesheet, and put `$("body").css({overflow : "hidden"});` in the `function toggleTopContent()`'s `else` statement, and `$("body").css({overflow : "auto"});` in `if`. That fixes your scroll bar.

To get the `header` stuck at the bottom, I'd say apply some fixed/absolute positioning to it within the `else` as well.

Comment: Heres the thing....I only want the scrollbars removed when the slider is coming down.  The way its set up now, removes the scrollbars totally. I dont want that.  The header also isnt locked at the bottom as the footer when i currently try it

Comment: @WillingLearner - Check the 2nd edit for the scrollbar fix, and idea for the header lock.

Comment: @Shango - it works fine in removing the scrollbar on the initial slidedown, but it dosent bring the scrollbar back on slideup. It appears the scrollbar is gone forever after i do it the first time. How would i remedy this?

Comment: @WillingLearner -- If you add `$("body").css({overflow : "auto"});` to the `if` it will re-enable it.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wgYMQ/

Comment: @Shango - That did it.  Thanks.  I tried your suggestion for locking the header at the bottom of the page using this: $("header").css({position : "fixed"}); as well as "absolute" but that dosen't seem to quite do the trick.  It blows up my layout to tell you the truth, especially when i slide the content back up.

Comment: @WillingLearner - You'd have to also apply `left : 0; bottom : 0;` for example, and then change it back to `position : relative` when you close it, but it's definitely a tricky idea... I'm sure it's doable, but it may require restructuring your document.

Comment: @Shango - Yea, im not quite sure what to do to make it happen. Doing your latest suggestion disabled the whole effect for me totally. Not sure why.

Comment: @WillingLearner - Yeah, the positioning of all the elements in your document would need to be reviewed really... I'll look at it later this weekend, see if I have any ideas.